# How to parse atom/xml content with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, meteor, atom-feed, google-data-api

I am [retrieving a Google Calendar Resource](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/calendar-resource/#retrieving_calendar_resources) via their [Data API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/calendar-resource/), which returns the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:apps="http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006">
  <apps:property name='resourceId' value='CR-NYC-14-12-BR'/>
  <apps:property name='resourceCommonName' value='Boardroom'/>
  <apps:property name='resourceDescription' value='Conference room in New York city, building 14, floor 12, Boardroom'/>
  <apps:property name='resourceType' value='CR'/>
</atom:entry>
```

I need to get the value of one of the fields, such as `resourceId` and store it in a variable. How can I parse this and obtain that value? I am using Meteor JS on the server side, which uses JavaScript. Therefore, the answer needs to use JavaScript. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For converting xml to json use: https://github.com/buglabs/node-xml2json

```
parser.toJson(xml, options);
```

Then it's simply the issue of iterating over the values.